# How to update single data when using Fauna and GraphQL

Tags: graphql, serverless, vercel, faunadb

I have some problems when using Fauna and GraphQL

When I use GraphQL to update data, all parameters are required

For example

```
// Schema

type User {
    username: String!
    password: String!
    phone: String!
}

// Mutation

mutation {
    updateUser(id: "xxxxx", {"phone": "+886 110220330"}){
        username,
        phone
    }
}

// Error
```

But I only want to update the `phone` data this time, how can I skip other parameters?

Although it can solve the problem when I delete the `Not null` of all attributes in `User` type,

But it doesn't look like a good way and safe

```
// after

//  Schema

type User {
    username: String
    password: String
    phone: String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a preview feature that you can use by adding a header to your GraphQL query.

```
X-Schema-Preview: partial-update-mutation
```

Once you do this, you will have access to a new mutation called `partialUpdateUser` which will make all of the input values optional.

See the docs for more information:  https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/graphql/previews/